# Migration IdentityServer .net core 2.1 to 3.1

Tags: c#, identityserver4

Have some issues with migrating the IdentityServer. There are several classes had changed their fields. And some of them I cant still find.

There are two classes'ConsentResponse' and 'AuthorizationRequest'.

Before migration, ConsentResponse had field ClientId. Now it's class Client which has ClientId
So => `AuthorizationRequest.ClientId to AuthorizationRequest.Client.ClientId.`

Now, I do not know how to 'migrate' AuthorizationRequests.ScopesRequested.
Also, can not figure out why am not able to initialize this type:

```
ConsentResponse grantedConsent = null;
//was before
grantedConsent = ConsentResponse.Denied;
//want to change, but compiler displays errors
grantedConsent = ConsentResponse.Error.Denied;
```

Also this property:

```
grantedConsent = new ConsentResponse
{
     RememberConsent = true, 
     //was
     ScopesConsented = request.ScopesRequested
     //need to change 
     ScopesConsented = request.
};
```

Comment: What is your connection string.  Migration requires a connection to the database and the connection string is failing.

Comment: @jdweng probably, i was not clear. mgration => updating the .net core. def there is a problem with new models of identity.

Comment: You cannot migrate if the connection fails.  I've seen lots a migration failure due to the connection string no longer working.  There could be a credential issue (OAuth or windows credentials) or changes from HTTP to HTTPS (TLS) are not working.  Often when migration you are moving to a different machine and/or server/database.